# Combining multirow with @-connected columns preserving alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multirow

In a `tabular` would like to combine `multirow` with `@`-connected columns and preserve alignment.
Let me explain with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lcr@{--}lc}
    T & t & min & max & Column added for edit\\
    \hline
    A & a & 1 & 2\\[1ex]
    \multirow{2}{*}{B} & b1 & \multirow{2}{*}{-2} & \multirow{2}{*}{1}\\
    & b2 &  & \\[1ex] % spurious --
    \multirow{2}{*}{C} & c1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{-1--1000}}\\
    & c2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\ % not aligned
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Edit: include convoluted vertical alignments}\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{D} & d1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{-1--1000}} & $\delta_1$\\
    & d2 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_2$}\\
    & d3 & 3 & 20 & \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the two ideas I had (`B` and `C`) to preserved alignment in a `multirow` context, either by `multirow`ing the two aligned columns or by using an extra `multicolumn` do not work.

How can I get the alignment I want?

**EDIT:** If possible, I also would like ‘convoluted’ vertical alignments to remain possible, i.e., preserve all rows and not simulate rows using line breaks in a single column.

Comment: What is the reason for those "convoluted" requirement? Imho, the table just gets unreadable from this formatting.

Comment: @Skillmon: I'm concerned with having the exact same vertical heights for each table row across all columns. I guess I can fix those if needed using `vphantom`.

Comment: Look at the edit to my answer. I recreated your convoluted example with the correct horizontal and vertical alignment. And if you want to move the "D" to the vertical centre use `\onecell{\\D}` instead of `D`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have a much simpler code with `makecell`: the eponymous command (and a few others) is designed to allow a common formatting and line breaks in standard cells. I added `booktabs` to have some vertical padding for horizontal rules, and replaced the endash separator with a hyphen dash, setting the last two columns in math mode (so the -2 is really a `minus  2`, not a `dash 2`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lc >{$}r<{$}@{\,-\,}>{$}l<{$}}
    T & t & \min & \max\\
    \midrule
    A & a & 1 & 2\\
\addlinespace
   B & \makecell{b1\\b2} &-2 & 1\\
\addlinespace
   C & \makecell{c1\\c2} & -1 & 1000 \\ %
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is my preferred answer, because the use of the convenient makecell package. In the end, I still needed to use a `multirow` command in a limited number of places, but could avoid it in the range columns using `makecell` in previous `multirow` columns.

Comment: Don't forget `makecell` also defines a `\multirowcell` command (simpler syntax, no `{*}{ required)!

Comment: Yes, that is what I used.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `\multirow` to combine several lines but `tabular` to put multiple lines in one cell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lcr@{--}l}
    T & t & min & max\\
    \hline
    A & a & 1 & 2\\[1ex]
    \multirow{2}{*}{B} & b1 & \multirow{2}{*}{-2} & \multirow{2}{*}{1}\\
    & b2 &  & \\[1ex] % spurious --
    \multirow{2}{*}{C} & c1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{-1--1000}}\\ % not aligned
    & c2 &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\[1ex]
    D & 
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
      d1\\d2
    \end{tabular}
    &
    -5&500
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Reproducing your convoluted example but with correct alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\onecell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}#1@{}}%
    #2%
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lcr@{--}lc}
    T & t & min & max & column added for edit\\
    \hline
    A & a & 1 & 2\\[1ex]
    B & \onecell{b1\\b2} & -2&1\\
    \noalign{\vskip1ex}
    C & \onecell{c1\\c2} & -1&1000\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{Edit: include convoluted vertical alignments}\\
    \hline
    D & \onecell{d1\\d2} & -1&1000 & \onecell{$\delta_1$\\~}\\
      & d3 & 3&20 &\multirow{-2}{*}{$\delta_2$}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as the one by Bernard, but it shows how more fine-grained control is possible if needed. (`\makecell` is defined using `tabular`.)

Comment: @equaeghe it is not the same but similar. And it solves your convoluted stuff, which bernard's answer doesn't. And `\makecell` is not more convenient than the small definition of `\onecell` while `\onecell` gives you easier access to the alignment (but the package introduces other stuff and if you need that, it is better to use `\makecell`).

Comment: I used a few `\multirow`s to deal with the convoluted parts; your suggestion works, but is not as convenient for me.